# How to get json file from HttpClient?

Tags: json, angular, authentication, httpclient, response

I am trying to get a `json` file from `HttpClient`, but I get a error when I add `.subscribe`

imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule, Request, Response, Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

My code:

[image]

When I add `.subscribe` (yellow marked in image) I got the following error. What does it mean?

> Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers:
>   Object, type: 3, url: null }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to make something very clear and organised you should create a service in angular and call the service from your component.

Like this for example:

**Service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";

// Set the http options
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "c31z" })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"

/**
 * Service to call all the API
 */
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  /**
   * Function to handle error when the server return an error
   *
   * @param error
   */
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error("An error occurred:", error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code. The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`
      );
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(error);
  }

  /**
   * Function to extract the data when the server return some
   *
   * @param res
   */
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || {};
  }

  /**
   * Function to GET what you want
   *
   * @param url
   */
  public getListOfGroup(url: string): Observable<any> {

    // Call the http GET
    return this.http.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

}

**Component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ApiService } from "../../services/api.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-example",
  templateUrl: "./example.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./example.component.css"]
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit{

  url = "/url/path/to/your/server";

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api
      .getListOfGroup(url)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
  }

}
```

My advice would be to follow the getting start of angular if not you will be quickly lost. [Service tutorial angular](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot! sorry if my question was not so clear!

Comment: While this is helpful advice for new developers, it doesn't currently answer the question that was asked.