# Facing issues on accessing json() in angular, HttpClient. Looking for alternatives

Tags: json, angular

I would like to get all the posts from 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'.
However the update of Http to HttpClient, not allowing to access "json()" (at response.json()).
Please guide for a solution.
Regards.

```
export class PostsComponent {
  posts: any[];
  constroctur(http: HttpClient) {
    http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.posts = response.json();
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: can't you access the data inside`response`? I don't know the structure of the returned data, but something like: `response.data` should contain all the posts returned.

Comment: It looks here you have your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056992/how-to-get-json-file-from-httpclient/52057607

Comment: With `HttpClient` you do not need to call `.json()`. By default, the response is already a json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is the pass the data type to the response argument "response : any[]".

```
export class PostsComponent {
  posts: any[];
  constroctur(http: HttpClient) {
    http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .subscribe((response : any[]) => {
    this.posts = response;
  });
 }
}
```

You must set the content type along with the request. It should look like below.

```
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
export class PostsComponent {
posts: any[];
constroctur(http: HttpClient) {
http
  .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',{headers})
  .subscribe((response : any[]) => {
    this.posts = response;
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
http
  .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .subscribe((response) => {
    this.posts = response;
  });
```

All you need to do, and arguably the best choice is setting the posts to the response. It's already a JavaScript object.

If, for whatever reason you require a JSON string, then you can look into JSON.Stringify:

```
 this.posts = JSON.stringify(response)
```