# When trying to get a json from an url using an old answer, it just throws an error. What could be thr problem?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get a json for my memory card game but when I try to implement this answer: [How to get json file from HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056992/how-to-get-json-file-from-httpclient)

It just shows the following error, which I have a hard time understanding:
[image]

My code is exactly like in the old answer. I imagine something changed over this 3 years that made it break.
What could be the solution?
What is the best way to get a json from a server using Angular?

I wish everyone a nice day!

Just in case here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "c31z" })
};

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error("An error occurred:", error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code. The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`
      );
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(error);
  }

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || {};
  }

public getListOfGroup(url: string): Observable<any> {

    // Call the http GET
    return this.http.get(url,httpOptions).pipe(map(this.extractData),catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the typings of the `extractData` method are very specific, but there's no typings to say what the body of the `http.get` response will be. Try the following (although I'm not sure if the body matches `Response` in your case)

```
this.http.get<Response>(...)
```

`Response` should really be an interface that matches the `json` object returned from the API call